# Is there anyway to use justify: space-between on li without nested divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there any way to remove these nested divs which contain the content and does it matter? Would there be any better tags to use than div? I am quite new to HTML so I'm not sure how important this is. I've heard a bit about the importance of semantic HTML but I've seen a lot of divs on many sites.

```css
@media screen and(max-width: 400px) {
  li {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 40%;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 80px;
  width: 200px;
}

li>div {
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul aria-label="Pork">
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul aria-label="Beef">
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>rib-eye</div>
      <div>$13.56/lb</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is nothing wrong with using them as you have done although maybe a `<p>` or a `<span>` would be better used semantically, as they are better suited for this type of content. `<div>` are primarily for separating blocks of content, whereas this is more spacing text.

However, there is no 100% right or 100% wrong.